# Determine if the integral converges: $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\arctan (px)}{x^q}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Determine if the integral converges:

$$\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\arctan (px)}{x^q}dx$$

where $p,q\in\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convergence is determined by whether $q>1$.  If so, then yes; if not, then no.  The parameter $p$ plays no part in this determination, except (as @coco mentions below) where, when $p=0$, the integral always converges.

Comment: @Ron Gordon I tried doing intergration by part, And I've got $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{x^{-q+1}}{p^2x^2+1}dx$ isn't $x^2$ affects the range?

Comment: If $p=0$ then the integral converges for all $q$

Comment: I do not understand the motivation for integrating by parts.  The question of convergence is a matter of comparison.  Arctan is constant at infinity, so the integral only converges when it decays faster than $1/x$.  The behavior at $x=1$ does not affect the question.

Comment: @Cocopuffs: true, true.  Thanks.

Comment: If $p=0$ it converges since the expression inside the integral is always $0$, right?

Comment: @TheAlchemist: correct.

Answer (score 2):

If $p\neq 0$
$$\frac{\arctan(px)}{x^q}\sim_\infty\frac{\pm\pi}{2x^q}$$
according to the sign of $p$ so the integral is convergent if $q>1$

and if $p=0$ the integral is convergent for all $q\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You're welcome.